# Best Way To Keep A User-Modified List Of Application Names

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, app-store, osx-lion

I'm looking for the best way to deal with a modifiable list of application names in an app's "Preferences" to be used as a filter.

I'd like to be able to have a few defaults in this on first run, and for the user to be able to modify this array.

So what's the best way to create and store a default array of Application Names (or anything, really) that can be modified and saved as a preference by a user?

NSArray saved somewhere? A really long entry in my defaults.plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to store an array of strings, the quickest and simplest way to do that is using `NSUserdefaults`. Very very easy to use.

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myArray forKey:@"StoredArray"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
 }


 -(void)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *myArray = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"StoredArray"];

    //do something with your array
}
```